# In crystal Why do I need to do matches.try &.[0]

Tags: crystal-lang

Here's some code:

```
matches =  /\/([a-z]+)\/(\d+)\/state\/([a-z]+)/.match(address) # line 1
puts matches[0]?                                               # line 2
puts matches.try &.[0]                                         # line 3
```

`matches` datatype is `(Regex::MatchData | Nil)` according to `typeof`. Yet, line 2, referring to `matches[0]` fails with a compilation error. And I don't understand line 3 at all!

Could someone clarify?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Line 2: As you say, the type of `matches` is `(Regex::MatchData | Nil)`. In case it happens to be `nil`, it wouldn't have the `#[]?` method, which makes the type checker angry. You are supposed to check whether `match` succeeded first:

```
matches =  /\/([a-z]+)\/(\d+)\/state\/([a-z]+)/.match(address)
if matches
  puts matches[0]?
end
```

Inside `if`, the type of `matches` is just `Regex::MatchData` (as we eliminated the `Nil` possibility), and the type checker can rest peacefully.

If you are sure your string will match, you can pacify the type checker with `not_nil!`, but that opens up a possibility of a runtime error, if your confidence in your data's conformance was unfounded:

```
puts matches.not_nil![0]?
```

Line 3: [`#try`](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.27.0/Object.html#try%28%26block%29-instance-method) will perform the block, except when the caller is `nil`, when it returns `nil`. No guards are needed because `#try` is explicitly defined on `Nil` (as well as on `Object`).

It uses the [shortcut syntax](https://crystal-lang.org/docs/syntax_and_semantics/blocks_and_procs.html#short-one-argument-syntax) for blocks, where `&.[0]` is kind of equivalent to `{ |x| x[0] }`.